# How to use tabIndex with jsx?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, tabindex

According to the react docs, this should work.

`<div tabIndex="0"></div>`

> But when I try this, it doesn't work
>   and my input is actually being skipped now!

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<input
tabIndex='0'/>
<input
tabIndex='1'/>
<input
tabIndex='2'/>
```

Comment: You need to use the correct spelling, you used incorrect spelling for tabIndex. It should be tabIndex instead of tabIdex

Comment: Oh sorry, I do have the correct spelling in my real code.

Answer (score 1):

You have typed tabIndex twice without the n, it should be:

```
<CustomRadio
tabIndex='0'/>
<CustomCheckbox
tabIndex='1'/>
<input
tabIndex='2'/>
```

I think you may also need to pass these props into your components, to the underlying element

Answer (score 0):

It is not a best-practice to put positive values for tabindex (tabIndex) as it could disrupt the tab navigation flow. You can use if there is no other way.

To achieve a specific order for tab navigation of elements, consider placing them in the DOM in a way that could achieve your requirement. More often than not, you can find a way to place them in the DOM to achieve your desired order of tab navigation.

Answer (score 0):

In JSX (JavaScript XML), you can use the tabIndex attribute just like you would in regular HTML. However, there's a small difference when using JSX: you should use curly braces {} to embed JavaScript expressions within the JSX code. Here's how you can correctly set the tabIndex attribute in JSX:

```
<input tabIndex={0} />
```